# Why when I use onClick with radio button make them have to click twice to make radio button to be selected?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

now, I using radio button to render 2 components differently I use onClick with radio button to `[isRepeat,setisRepeat] setState` value

```
  <input
     required
     id="singleClass"
     name="classType"
     type="radio"
     className="inputContainer"
     value={1}
     OnClick={() => setisRepeat("oneTime")}
     ></input>

     <label>ครั้งเดียว</label>
   <input
     required
     id="repeatClass"
     name="classType"
     type="radio"
     className="inputContainer"
     value={2}
     onClick={() => setisRepeat("repeat")}
     ></input>
```

and render component like this

```
    {isRepeat === "oneTime" && (
        <>...</>
    )}
    {isRepeat === "repeat" && (
        <div>...</div>
    )}
```

but when I using `onClick()` with radio button, It's make user to click "twice" to make radio button checked

(actually, `setState` work fine when click radio button but radio button didn't be checked. It should be checked and `setState` at the same time to make user not confuse)

ps. I already using `document.getElementByName('classType').value === 1 or 2`   to render different items, but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onChange` with `input` as:

```
onChange={() => setisRepeat("oneTime")}
```

instead of `onClick`

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-banzai-sf1x7?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
export default function App() {
  const [isRepeat, setisRepeat] = useState(""); // You can also give the initial value

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        required
        id="singleClass"
        name="classType"
        type="radio"
        className="inputContainer"
        value={1}
        onChange={() => setisRepeat("oneTime")}
      ></input>

      <label>ครั้งเดียว</label>
      <input
        required
        id="repeatClass"
        name="classType"
        type="radio"
        className="inputContainer"
        value={2}
        onChange={() => setisRepeat("repeat")}
      ></input>

      <br />

      {isRepeat === "oneTime" && <> One Time </>}
      {isRepeat === "repeat" && <div> Repeat </div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, It's already work. At first It's didn't work until I find out It has a problem with my component too, So I fixed the components things and fix the radio after with your solution after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onChange instead of onClick handler and checked property along with it.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [isRepeat, setisRepeat] = useState("");
const onClickHandler = (type) => {
  if (type === "singleClass") {
     setisRepeat("singleClass");
  } else {
     setisRepeat("repeatClass");
  }
};
return (
<div className="App">
  <input
    required
    name="singleClass"
    type="radio"
    className="inputContainer"
    value={1}
    checked={isRepeat === "singleClass"}
    onChange={() => {
      onClickHandler("singleClass");
    }}
  ></input>

  <label>ครั้งเดียว</label>
  <input
    required
    name="repeatClass"
    type="radio"
    className="inputContainer"
    value={2}
    checked={isRepeat === "repeatClass"}
    onChange={() => {
      onClickHandler("repeatClass");
    }}
  ></input>
  {isRepeat === "singleClass" && (
    <>
      <p>One time component Triggered </p>
    </>
  )}
  {isRepeat === "repeatClass" && <div>Repeat component Triggered </div>}
</div>
);
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mayer-r6j6e?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

In the first input you have a typo. You have `OnClick` but you want `onClick`

It works for me with one click like this
(I removed a few props to make it shorter)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Demo = () => {
  const [isRepeat, setIsRepeat] = useState('');
  return (
    <>
      <input type="radio" value={1} onClick={() => setIsRepeat('oneTime')}></input>

      <label>ครั้งเดียว</label>
      <input type="radio" value={2} onClick={() => setIsRepeat('repeat')}></input>

      {isRepeat === 'oneTime' && <span>One Time</span>}
      {isRepeat === 'repeat' && <span>repeat</span>}
    </>
  );
};
export default Demo;
```